# Can I run my server on SSH port?

Tags: networking, ssh, ports, http-proxy, bypass

I set up server for a game on my PC and by default it works on port 25565(minecraft!) and I want people from outside my Uni network to connect to the server. I want to know if there's any way to use any of few opened ports? Ports which are open: 1022(ssh), 3127(http-proxy), 3128(http-proxy) and 80(obviously).

Comment: Most likely not. Even though the ports are open for you to get data from in to out, for the other way around you most likely need to redirect ports, something that you probably can't arrange.

Comment: These ports are open for outside too, not only on local network

Comment: Maybe, but how does traffic knows how to connect to your port? It doesn't. For that, port forwarding rules needs to be setup. Its more likely those ports are open and redirect to one or more servers inside your university, so you tell people, I have setup a minecraft server, they try to join and their minecraft then tries to connect to a server on your uni instead of your minecraft instance, and they get a connection error.

Comment: I have access to my uni's server and it has ssh port opened and it probably has connections from 1022. Can I use that as tunnel or proxy or anything that would work?

Comment: No, because the port already ends at the server. You need access to the router to alter port forwardings, unless you can install minecraft on that server.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install server on uni's server which I have access to but I know I can setup this server as vpn, can I just use this server as vpn and let people connect like this Internet->Uni's server set up as vpn -> My PC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86495/discussion-between-arek-zylkowski-and-lpchip).